# Organisational membership renewals failing

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

Bit of a strange one. We have an organisation with an organisational membership. They have a contact with view and update permissions to and from the organisation. When they go to renew the membership it pulls through the membership fine, but when they try to submit the contribution form it shows this error:

*This organisation already has an organisation membership*

The membership's status is current and expires in about six weeks.

The membership was originally created offline by an admin - could this be the cause of it perhaps?

We're on Civi 5.52.2 and WordPress 6.2.2

Answer (score 0):

As well as having the permissioned relationship, the contact doing the renewal also needs to be marked as being a 'current employee'

Comment: I thought that too, but the user renewing is marked as a current employee

Comment: And the Permissions on the Relationship are correct?

Comment: I think they're fine - this is how it looks: https://pasteboard.co/P99e105ptW49.png

Comment: not sure what to suggest. i could say 'test this on the https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org site just to confirm you haven't found a new bug'. in general what you describe, unless i am missing some nuance, should just work